# How to create html partials?

Tags: html

When webpage layout is repeated throughout website, what do you use to escape repeating the code? (analogous to rails html layouts with their *yield*). 
I guess I just can't properly form a google request, there must be something widespread.

Comment: Dreamweaver has templates. All depends on what type of site you are making, plain HTML, PHP, CMS etc

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of systems for this. I personally use [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/), although there are many different frameworks. In general these are called Templating Systems, and they go through your HTML and respond to commands to generate text.